# ASP.NET MVC How to correctly map a parameter in url-routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have the following route

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Segnalazioni_CercaSegnalazioni",
            "Segnalazioni/CercaSegnalazioni/{flag}",
            new { controller = "Segnalazioni", action = "CercaSegnalazioni", flag = 7 }
        );
```

that maps to the following methon of the class SegnalazioniController:

```
    public ActionResult CercaSegnalazioni(int flag)
    {
        ViewData["collezioneSegnalazioni"] = Models.Segnalazioni.Recupera(flag);
        System.Xml.Linq.XElement x = (System.Xml.Linq.XElement)ViewData["collezioneSegnalazioni"];
        return View("Index");
    }
```

How come the link `http://localhost:1387/Segnalazioni/CercaSegnalazioni/1` gives me the error

```
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'flag' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult CercaSegnalazioni(Int32)' in 'RecuperoPagatiMvc.Controllers.SegnalazioniController'. To make a parameter optional its type should be either a reference type or a Nullable type.
Nome parametro: parameters
```

Comment: sounds to me like you're not hitting that route. if you move the route posted to the top of your route table does it work?

Answer (score 1):

Post all your routes. It sounds like your URL is being handled by a different route than this one. Remember, the order you list your routes does matter. Therefore, if you have another route BEFORE this one that this URL can map to, it will.

Answer (score 0):

[MvcContrib](http://www.codeplex.com/MVCContrib) contains route debugger. Use it and you'll see which route is called for this url. [Here](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Routing) are some instructions how to enable it